# JAVA Class and Dreamweaver integration

Tags: java, class, jsp, methods, dreamweaver

I am creating jsp application. I have created jsp pages using dreamweaver and some java classes using Netbeans.

what i want to do now and want to know, can i like make my classes methods and variables appear as tags or hints in dreamweaver? like when you type

```
<p><% out.println("pink")%></p>
```

above, the println will automatically appear with the list of other hints when you type **out.**.. so when i have myClass java class...

```
<p><%=myClass.getMyMethod()%></p>
```

the .getMyMethod with all the other methods will appear.

I hope it's clear. Just asking...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its better to design the view part in Dreamweaver. And migrate the *.jsp files to Netbeans IDE. But this feature is supported in latest versions of Dreamweaver.

Comment: im using cs5. also, i have created a complete working apps using dreamweaver and jsp/netbeans. i'd like to try your suggesting long before, my problem is, im using plugins like jquery and other javascript. im worried that the layout and other javascript might have problems. actually my codes, are really messy,...i will try to use netbeans or eclipse now. i want to make my work really good and mess free. and easy to be understood by other, so if incase ill be out in the company, it could be easily modfied.. still, thanks!